# Advice on why my python has stopped working?

Tags: python, break

the code below is for a question game and only the films work but for some reason its stopped working.

```
player1 = True

error1 = True

q1 = 5

score1 = 0

while player1 == True:

  while error1 == True:

    select1 = input("choose a catagory; films, games, food or sports ")

    if select1 == "films":
      error1 = False
      filmlist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]
      while q1 >0:
         filmselect = random.choice(filmlist)
      
         if filmselect == "1":
           a = "what color is a sith lightsaber? "
           b = "red"
           filmlist.remove("1")
       

         if filmselect == "2":
          a = "what animal ran the ice cream shop in zootropolis"
          b = "elephant"
          filmlist.remove("2")
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: What do you mean by "its stopped working"? What happens when `filmselect` is something other than "1" or "2"? Where are you decreasing `q1` in your `while` loop so it can actually exit?

Comment: " its stopped working." is of little help to anybody trying to assist.  What has stopped working? What indication that is not working do you receive?  Please clarify your needs.